# Getting Error message "Traceback (most recent call last)" when using pandas to work on an Excel file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read the string type data from an excel file using Pandas. I can read the head of the whole file. However, when I try to locate the first column or second column of the file, I am getting an error of "Traceback (most recent call last)". My .xlsx file has all text type data. I don't know if there is anything wrong with the format of my .xlsx file. My code is as below.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("document name.xlsx",index_col=0)
df.head()  # It works here to show me the head of the whole file. 

df['column 1'].head() # It does NOT work for locating the first column.The error message is listed below. 
 KeyError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in 
 get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
 2656             try:
 -> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
 2658             except KeyError:

 pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

 pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

 pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
 pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

 pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
 pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

 KeyError: 'column1'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-a04362371301> in <module>
----> 1 df['column1'].head()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'column1'
```

Comment: Your error here is that the column doesn't exist, try `print(df.columns) `and see what their names are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the name of your columns,
surely **column1 is not among the names of its columns**:

```
print(df.columns)
```

If you want to show first column of your dataframe
regardless of the name of this you can use [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[:,0]
```

Comment: I am glad to help:)